# binary search guessing number recursively

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search

I am coding a binary search algorithm and I want to get the count minimum guesses does it take to search the number that I provide.suppose that the number which I provide is 33, then it should count 7 steps.

```
Step no     number guessed   result     range of possible values
0                                                 1-100
1              50           too high              1-49
2              25           too low               26-49
3              37           too high              26-36 
4              31           too low               32-36
5              34           too high              32-33
6              32           too low               33-33
7              33           correct
```

so this is my code for this

```
package binarySearch;

public class Binary {

    int gussedNo;
    public static   int count =0;

     void search(int lowerBound,int upperBound,int num){
        gussedNo=upperBound+lowerBound/2;
        count();
        if(gussedNo==num){
            System.out.println(count);}
            else if(gussedNo>num){

                upperBound=gussedNo-1;

                search(lowerBound,upperBound,num);

                }
            if(gussedNo<num){

                lowerBound=gussedNo+1;
                search(lowerBound,upperBound,num);




        }

        }
    int count(){
        count=count+1;
        return count;
    }

}
```

I created a a separate method. here is my my main class..

```
package binarySearch;

public class MainClass {
    public static void main (String[] args){

        Binary search= new Binary();

        search.search(1, 100,33 );

    }
}
```

Here I have given lowerbound as 1 and uperbound as 100, and the number I want to count guesses for it is 33.
But when I  execute the code I get the count as 68..but  it should be 7 according to binary search

Comment: "the **minimum** guesses" for any number is always 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the line where you create the next guess:

```
gussedNo=upperBound+lowerBound/2;
```

Due to mathematical operators precedence in Java, this line is the same as having:

```
gussedNo=upperBound+(lowerBound/2);
```

Which is clearly not performing a binary search, and thus, not what you wanted. You can solve this by explicitly adding the brackets:

```
gussedNo = (upperBound + lowerBound) / 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

here is your problem
`gussedNo=upperBound+lowerBound/2;`

you forgot abour operatots order execution
it should be
`gussedNo=(upperBound+lowerBound)/2;`